# Specific Heat of Liquid Helium

Tags: solid-state-physics, phase-transition, superfluidity

At the lambda point, the specific heat of Liquid Helium diverges. After searching for a curve, I've found only measured curves.

Is there a theoretical curve for this transition?

Comment: [A quick Google found this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3941), though this only calculates the form of the curve above the critical point.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found that paper when searching. I've yet to find a curve that described what happens below the point.